# Rails validator with format that doesn't all square brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I have a validator for an email address with a format but it allows a user to create an email address with square brackets in it. The validator is as follows:

`validates :email,presence: true, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }`

I need to add some more regex to it to make sure that square brackets ("[ ]") are not allowed.

Comment: The `[^@\s]+` part matches one or more symbols other than `@` and whitespace. It allows `[` and `]` and many more. What are your exact requirements? Just excude `[` and `]` from the character class? Add them - `/\A([^\]\[@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^[+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i
```

You can also use some libraries like [this](https://github.com/balexand/email_validator)